# Calculating $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^2 - (a+1)x + a}{x^3-a^3}$ using L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^2 - (a+1)x + a}{x^3-a^3}$$

Using L'Hospital's rule I get:

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{2x - (a+1)}{3x^2} = \frac{2a - (a+1)}{3a^2} = 0$$

But actually the limit is

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{2x - (a+1)}{3x^2} = \frac{a-1}{3a^2}$$

Can you help me find my mistake?

Comment: Why did you decide that $\frac{2a-(a+1)}{3a^2}=0$?

Comment: How do you get that your limit is zero? 2a-a-1=a-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2a-(a+1)=2a-a-1=a-1.$$ I think this is the only mistake you have.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{2x - (a+1)}{3x^2} = \frac{2a - (a+1)}{3a^2} \ne 0$$

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{2x - (a+1)}{3x^2} = \frac{2a - (a+1)}{3a^2} = \frac{ a - 1 }{3a^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{2x - (a+1)}{3x^2} = \frac{2a - (a+1)}{3a^2} = 0$ is incorrect.

If you check more carefully, you'll see that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{2x - (a+1)}{3x^2} = \frac{2a - (a+1)}{3a^2} = \frac{2a-a-1}{3a^2}=\frac{a-1}{3a^2}$